# fread hanging, C++ with pipes

Tags: c++, file-io, pipe

I'm writing a tictactoe application which communicates between a server and client file. Currently, my program hangs when trying to read in the players move. The client is showing successful write to the pipe but the server is not reading the information. Any help would be appreciated. Heres the offending code from both portions. Edit: I just realized the formatting got completely buggered in the copy/paste, I am sorry.

client main() :

```
//used to define int holder for server read in
const int MAX = 2;
//used to define buffers to transfer information
const int BUFFERS = 10;
//path of the global pipe
const string PRIMARY = "/home/mking/GPipe";

int main() {

    //variables
    size_t result;
    srand(time(NULL) );
  int s = rand() % 10000;
    if (s < 1000) { s += 1000; }
    cout << s << endl;
  string userWrite = "/temp/" + to_string(s);
  s = rand() % 10000;
    if (s < 1000) { s += 1000; }
    cout << s << endl;
  string serverWrite = "/temp/" + to_string(s);

    cout << PRIMARY << endl;

    cout << "User pipe is " << userWrite << endl;
    cout << "Server pipe is " << serverWrite << endl;

    // send personal pipe information through global pipe to server
  FILE * comms = fopen(PRIMARY.c_str(), "w");
    cout << "Comms open" << endl;

  result = fwrite(userWrite.c_str(), 1, userWrite.length(), comms);
    if (result < userWrite.length()) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, userfifo" << endl; }

  result = fwrite(serverWrite.c_str(), 1, serverWrite.length(), comms);
    if (result < userWrite.length()) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, serverfifo" << endl; }

    cout << "Comms written to" << endl;

    //done with comms so close it
  fclose(comms);

    // for some reason sending /tmp/ caused a hang also, so i improvised
    userWrite.erase(2,1);
    serverWrite.erase(2,1);

    // make the personal pipes
    cout << userWrite << " " << serverWrite << endl;
  mkfifo(userWrite.c_str(), 0777);
  mkfifo(serverWrite.c_str(), 0777);

    // open the personal pipes with read or write privelege
    cout << "fifos made" << endl;
    FILE * pwrite = fopen(userWrite.c_str(), "w");
    cout << "pwrite open" << endl;
    FILE * pread = fopen(serverWrite.c_str(), "r");
    cout << "pread open" << endl;

    // if either pipe did not get made correctly, print an error
    if (pwrite == NULL ) { cout << "pwrite is wrong" << endl; }
    if (pread == NULL ) { cout << "pread is wrong" << endl; }

    // used to transfer information between pipes
  string buffer = "/temp/0000";
  string catcher = "/temp/0000";

    // initialize curses functions
    initscr();
  noecho();
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
    cbreak();
  WINDOW * screen = newwin(LINES/2, COLS/2, 0, 0);
    wclear(screen);
    keypad(screen,TRUE);

    //wait for input before playing the game
    int c = getch();
  displayOpening(screen);
  c = getch();

    //initialize the game data types
  int row = 0;
  int column = 0; 
  vector<pair<int, int> > userMoves;
  vector<pair<int,int> > serverMoves;
    int charInt[MAX];
    bool invalid = 0;

    //until game is over or user exits
  while (1) {
        // update the board
    displayBoard(screen,userMoves,serverMoves, row, column, invalid);

        // based on user input, do stuff, supports wsad or arrow keys
    switch(c = getch() ) {

        // if go up, move up a row or go back to bottom if at top
    case KEY_UP:
        case 'w':
      if (row == 0) { row = 2; }
      else { row--; }
      break;

        // if go down, move down a row or go back to the top if at bottom
    case KEY_DOWN:
        case 's':
      if (row == 2) { row = 0; }
      else { row++; }
      break;

        // if go left, move left a column or go back to the far right if at far left 
    case KEY_LEFT:
        case 'a':
      if (column == 0) { column = 2; }
      else { column--; }
      break;

        // if go right, move right a column or go back to the far left if at far right
    case KEY_RIGHT:
        case 'd':
      if (column == 2) { column = 0; }
      else { column++; }
      break;

        // if spacebar is pressed, enter move if valid, otherwise tell invalid and get more input
    case ' ':
      if (checkX(row, column, userMoves, serverMoves)) {
                invalid = 0;

                // no longer used function, thought maybe was the issue
                //addX(row,column,userMoves,buffer);

                //catch information in buffer to send to server
                buffer[8] = (row + '0');
                buffer[9] = (column + '0');

                //cout << "buffer 0 and 1 are " << int(buffer[0]) << " " << int(buffer[1]) << endl; 
                // add newest move to the list of user moves
                userMoves.push_back(make_pair(row,column));

                // check if the game is over, send a game over message to server if so and exit/clean up pipes
                if (checkValid(userMoves,serverMoves) == 0 || (userMoves.size() + serverMoves.size() == 9) ) {
                    youwin(screen);
                    buffer[8] = (3 + '0');
                    buffer[9] = (3 + '0');
                    result = fwrite(buffer.c_str(), 1, buffer.length(), pwrite);
                    if (result < BUFFERS) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, usermove" << endl; }
                    fclose(pread);
                    fclose(pwrite);
                    unlink(userWrite.c_str());
                    unlink(serverWrite.c_str());
                    endwin();
                    return 0;
                }

                //mvwaddch(screen, 12, 1, 'k');
                //wrefresh(screen);

                //cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << buffer << " " << buffer.length() << endl;

                // write newest move to server, currently where hangs!!!!!!
                result = fwrite(buffer.c_str(),1,buffer.length(),pwrite);
                if (result < BUFFERS) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, usermove" << endl; }
                //cout << endl << "written successfully" << endl;

                //mvwaddch(screen,12,1,'l');
                //wrefresh(screen);

                // read in server counter move
                result = fread(&catcher[0],1,BUFFERS,pread);
                if (result < BUFFERS) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "read error, servermove" << endl; }

                // catch newest computer move
                charInt[0] = (catcher[8] - '0');
                charInt[1] = (catcher[9] - '0');

                // if the server says it won, clean up pipes and exit
                if (charInt[0] == 3 && charInt[1] == 3) {
                    youlose(screen);
                    fclose(pread);
                    fclose(pwrite);
                    unlink(userWrite.c_str());
                    unlink(serverWrite.c_str());
                    endwin();
                    return 0;
                }

                // check if the server made a valid move
                if (checkX(charInt[0], charInt[1], userMoves, serverMoves)) { invalid = 1; }

                //addX(charInt[0],charInt[1],serverMoves,catcher);

                // add newest server move to list of server moves
                serverMoves.push_back(make_pair(charInt[0],charInt[1]));

                // if server has won or a draw, tell the server and clean up pipes/exit
                if (checkValid(userMoves,serverMoves) == 0) {
                    youlose(screen);
                    buffer[8] = (3 + '0');
                    buffer[9] = (3 + '0');
                    result = fwrite(&buffer[0],1,BUFFERS,pwrite);
                    if (result < BUFFERS) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, usermove" << endl; }
                    fclose(pread);
                    fclose(pwrite);
                    unlink(userWrite.c_str());
                    unlink(serverWrite.c_str());
                    endwin();
                    return 0;
                }

      }

            // if the move was invalid say so
      else { invalid = 1; }
      break;

        // if user wants to exit, tell the server and clean up/exit
    case 'q':
            buffer[8] = 3 + '0';
            buffer[9] = 3 + '0';
            result = fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(char),BUFFERS,pwrite);
            if (result < BUFFERS) { cout << endl << endl << endl << endl << endl << "write error, usermove" << endl; }
      fclose(pread);
      fclose(pwrite);
            unlink(userWrite.c_str());
            unlink(serverWrite.c_str());
            endwin();
      return 0;
      break;
    default:
      break;
    }

  }

  return 0;
}
```

server main() :

```
const int GRID = 9;
const int MAX_G = 10;
const int MAX_L = 10;
const string PRIMARY="/home/mking/GPipe";

int main() {

    // variables to hold personal pipe input
  char userWrite[MAX_L];
  char serverWrite[MAX_L];


    // open global pipe and prepare for input
    cout << PRIMARY << endl;
  FILE * comms = fopen(PRIMARY.c_str(), "r");
    cout << "comms open" << endl;
  pid_t pid;
  bool valid = 1;
    int charInt[MAX_G];
    char prev[] = "/temp/0000";
    size_t result;

    // run until forced to close
  while(1) {

        // get the personal pipe names

        //cout << "about to read user" << endl;
    result = fread(&userWrite[0], sizeof(char),MAX_L,comms);
        if (result < MAX_L && result > 0) { cout << "read error, user" << endl; }
        //cout << "read user" << endl;
    result = fread(&serverWrite[0], sizeof(char), MAX_L,comms);
        if (result < MAX_L && result > 0) { cout << "read error, server" << endl; }
        //cout << "read server" << endl;
        //cout << "User pipe is " << userWrite << endl;
        //cout << "Server pipe is " << serverWrite << endl;

        // if a new pipe was detected, fork and play against a client
        if (strcmp(prev, userWrite) != 0) { pid = fork(); }
        strcpy(prev, userWrite);

        // if a chiled, play against a client
    if (pid == 0) {

            //close comms and open personal pipes
            cout << "In child" << endl;
      fclose(comms);

            string user(userWrite);
            string server(serverWrite);

            // was having issues with fread earlier also, roundabout fix
            user.erase(2,1);
            server.erase(2,1);

            // set up pipes
            cout << "opened pipes " << user << " " << server << endl;
      FILE * userFifo = fopen(user.c_str(), "r");
            cout << "opened user pipe" << endl;
      FILE * serverFifo = fopen(server.c_str(), "w");
            cout << "opened server pipe" << endl;

            // set up data for server to check moves
      pair<int,int> move;
      vector<pair<int,int> > userMoves;
      vector<pair<int,int> > serverMoves;

      char buffer[MAX_G] = {'/','t','e','m','p','/','0','0' };
      char filler[MAX_G];
      vector<bool> untaken (GRID, 1);

            // while game not over
      while (valid) {
                // get a new move, HANGS HERE!!!!!

                cout << "waiting for user move" << endl;
                result = fread(&filler[0], sizeof(char), MAX_G, userFifo);
                if (result < MAX_G) { cout << "read error, usermove" << endl; }
                cout << "move read in" << endl;

                // catch user move
                charInt[0] = filler[6] - '0';
                charInt[1] = filler[7] - '0';
                cout << charInt[0] << " " << charInt[1] << endl;

                // if user says game over, close pipes
                if (charInt[0] == 3 && charInt[1] == 3) {
                    fclose(userFifo);
                    fclose(serverFifo);
                    exit(0);
                }

                // add user move to list of moves
                userMoves.push_back(make_pair(charInt[0], charInt[1]));

                // mark location of taken moves
                untaken[(userMoves.back().first * 3 + userMoves.back().second)] = 0;

                // see if game can be ended and add a server move
                valid = checkX(userMoves,serverMoves, untaken);
                untaken[(serverMoves.back().first * 3 + serverMoves.back().second)] = 0;

                //prepare server move for writing
            buffer[6] = serverMoves.back().first + '0';
                buffer[7] = serverMoves.back().second + '0';

                //buffer[0] = -1;
                //buffer[1] = -1;

                // write servermove to client
                //cout << buffer[0] << " " << buffer[1] << endl;
                result = fwrite(&buffer[0],sizeof(char),MAX_G,serverFifo);
                if (result < MAX_G) { cout << "write error, servermove" << endl; }
      }

            // close pipes if game is over
      fclose(userFifo);
      fclose(serverFifo);
      exit(0);
    }

  }
  fclose(comms);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use files for this, use _actual_ pipes: http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe

Comment: I'm not sure of the difference. I did use mkfifo to create pipes which is how I am transferring data. I am just using fread and fwrite to put the data into the pipes.

Comment: Ah. The difference is that `mkfifo` creates *named* pipes (which work like files) and `pipe` creates *unnamed* pipes (which connect between parent and child processes, and must be created prior to the `fork` call).

Comment: mkfifo might not be what you want here: `Once  you have created a FIFO special file in this way, any process can open it for reading or writing, in the same way as an ordinary file.  However, it has to be open at both ends simultaneously before you can proceed to do any input or output operations on it.  Opening a FIFO for reading normally blocks until some other process opens the same FIFO for writing, and vice versa.` http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkfifo

Comment: Oh, I did know that but did not know what you meant. The requirement for this is that named pipes are used unfortunately. And I believe the block should be broken when client writes to the named pipe which server reads from. This is not happening though.

Comment: Pipes do not work in packets. If you try to fread MAX_G characters, fread will not return until it reads MAX_G characters, and you are not writing that many.

Comment: i forgot to include my global constants, MAX_G is a const int = 10, which is the size of buffer in client. I will look over that again and include my global definitions in the code portions though in case i missed it.

Comment: You don't check for errors when you open your pipe. I would check for errors and if found print out `std::strerror(errno);`

Comment: Is `/temp/` really accessible to your process? Did you mean `/tmp/`?

Comment: /temp/ is not accessible, but for a reason that defied my logic and which i pulled a friend in to verify it was happening, server would read /temp/0123 but would hang on /tmp/0123 or just 0123. i cant explain it so i worked around it. the pipe names are set to /tmp/0123 however, i just had to set them inside the file instead of sending tmp through the pipe

Comment: I added error checking to the pipe opens and makes, however none are returning errors

Comment: If you want to write MAX_G bytes, pass a buffer of MAX_G bytes and MAX_G as size. You are not doing that.

Comment: I'll look into that when I pick it back up in the morning thanks!